# Search results not showing full post, only excerpt (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, search, filter

this is my first time posting on this site so apologies if the question isn't totally appropriate but I'm building a portfolio site for my brother who is a composer and he needs his music library to be able to be checkbox filter-able. The problem is that when I conduct a search with filters, the results show only the excerpt, and not the audio player like I need.

[Library page displaying the full posts with audio player](http://samijano.com/library/)

[Search results page showing just the post title and nothing else](http://samijano.com/?s=793dc11df1&formid=31&taxo%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=category&taxo%5B0%5D%5Bterm%5D%5B%5D=epic&wqsfsubmit=Search)

Also, excuse the sheer crudeness of the site. I just started it this morning... Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you ask a question, it's better to post relevant code with the question.

Answer (score 0):

To show the full content you have to use `the_content` function, in your `search.php` file replace the following

```
<?php the_excerpt(); // partial content ?>
```

with

```
<?php the_content(); // full content ?>
```

Also remember. `the_excerpt` function strips out all `HTML` tags so it could be a problem, you can read [this article](http://heera.it/show-vipers-video-excerpt).